# Why is there an "in" in "Of America's million millionaires in, the average age is 63"?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, sentence-construction

[image]

> Of *America's* million millionaires *in*, the average age is 63.

https://www.shanbay.com/review/learning/42379858288

1. Why is there an "in"? (The main question)
2. How about using "American" replacing "America's"?

Comment: What is the source? Is this a translation?

Comment: It's better to include that source with a link if possible. The "in" part is a typo. I think they meant to write "in 1985".

Comment: It's a dictionary. https://www.shanbay.com/review/learning/42379858288

Comment: @Max How clever you are! After reading your comment, I reviewed both English and its Chinese translation. According to the translation, which I usually overlook, it misses "1985".